# Threading, parallel 'while True' loops

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I know this was asked many times, yet Im not able to get this to work.
I have two separate functions, both using *while True* loop:

```
def function_1():
    while True:
        #do something
```

and

```
def function_2():
    while True:
        #do something also
```

I have tried running them with *threading* like this:

```
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=function_1(), args=())
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=function_2(), args=())

t_1.start()
t_2.start()
```

The problem is that it executes only the first one. I've also tried wrapping this into a function and call it but the results are similar.
Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=function_1)
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=function_2)
```

You gotta remove the brackets while passing the function to the target. In Python, functions can be treated as objects so that's why its possible

When you put brackets python essentially waits for the `function_1()` to return another function ,which is not happening. So when you start thread 1 since `function_1` is a while True func, its stuck there .

Read  [functions are first class objects - Dan Bader](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions)